# how to stop yum from trying other mirrors

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I'm sitting behind a proxy on my CentOS 6.4 box and I can't perform a 'yum update' because yum keeps killing the slow downloads and trying another mirror.  The problem is that the way our proxy works with big files is it will download them fully to the proxy first, perform a virus scan, then forward them to the client (my CentOS box).  While it's downloading to the proxy server the perceived transfer speed to my box seems to slow to a trickle.

Is there a way I can tell yum to not try other mirrors?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.  The timeout yum uses before trying other mirrors can be set in the /etc/yum.conf file.  The default is 30 (seconds).  I set mine to 300 and yum was successfully able to update and install packages.

```
timeout=300
```